# minitoc package: overfull \hbox

Tags: table-of-contents, warnings, minitoc

Does anyone of you know how to format a ToC created with the `minitoc` package in LaTeX? My problem is that I always get the following warning:

```
./hauptdokument.mtc.1:21:Overfull \hbox (2.83262 pt too wide) detected
```

This happens if the page number is greater than 10 e. g. 1-10 or 1-12. I've read the `minitoc` documentation but I didn't find a solution to widen the box around the page numbers so I appreciate any help you could give.

I use the following commands to format my minitoc:

```
\mtcselectlanguage{german}

\renewcommand{\mtcSfont}{\small\rm}

\dominitoc
```

Answer (score 8):

The warning is not specific to `minitoc`. The standard classes typeset ToC page numbers in a box of width `\@pnumwidth` (note: this is a command, not a length), and `minitoc` adopts the setting of `\@pnumwidth`. The command's default value is 1.55em, which is sufficient for three-digit numbers. In your case, the warning disappears by setting `\@pnumwidth` to 2.5em.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{minitoc}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{2.5em}% default is 1.55em
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thepage}{XY-\arabic{page}}

\begin{document}

\dominitoc% Initialization
\faketableofcontents

\chapter{bla}
\minitoc% Creating an actual minitoc

\section{blubb}

\section{foo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Die lockstep! Thank you for your very useful answer. I knew about @pnumwidth but it has never worked for me because I've allways used it between the \begin{document}..\end{document} tags. From your post I've learned to use the before opening the document. Many thanks and best regards. Florian

Comment: Small addition to lockstep answer, make sure that `\@tocrmarg` (default 2.55em) is greater than `\@pnumwidth`.

Comment: @user865294 a) I hope you don't want me to die b) You may thank me by upvoting my answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote) and possibly accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark).